# What implicit conversions are supported when using < and > operators?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have got a struct:

```
public struct Decibel
{
    public readonly double Value;

    public Decibel (double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Decibel (double decibels)
    {
        return new Decibel (decibels);
    }

    public static implicit operator double (Decibel decibels)
    {
        return decibels.Value;
    }
}
```

And now I can do:

```
bool x = new Decibel (0) < new Decibel (1);
```

It seems the compiler is smart enough to convert `Decibel` to `double`, and then use the `<` operator for doubles?

I had different `struct` named `Duration`, which was wrapping `TimeSpan`.  It had implicit conversions for `TimeSpan` to/from `Duration`, but the `<` and `>` operators are not working for it.

Does c# only recognize conversion between primitive types?

Comment: There is related information from Eric Lippert here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8529811/106159

Comment: `implicit` conversions make it very easy to shoot yourself in the foot. They should be used rarely and carefully. And an implicit conversion to a primitive type is just a bad idea.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: i know, im trying it use carefuly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly note that C# will allow a maximum of ONE implicit user-defined conversion between types.

So when you compare two instances of `Decibel`, the compiler sees that it can use a user-defined implicit conversion to convert a `Decibel` to a `double` with which to compare.

However when you compare two instances of `Duration`, the compiler cannot find any *single* implicit conversion which it can use to allow the comparison. The compiler will not consider any user-defined comparison operators for any of the types to which the type can be implicitly converted. It will only look for built-in comparison operators for any of the types to which the type can be implicitly converted.

Therefore the compiler will not use the implicit conversion to `TimeSpan`, even though `TimeSpan` provides a user-defined comparison operator that could theoretically be used.

Also note that even if the `TimeSpan` class provided an implicit conversion to `double`, the compiler would still not use it, since it will only consider at most one implicit user-defined conversion in the chain of implicit conversions.

In other words, given these structs:

```
public struct Number
{
    public readonly double Value;

    public Number(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Number(double duration)
    {
        return new Number(duration);
    }

    public static implicit operator double(Number number)
    {
        return number.Value;
    }
}

public struct NumberWrapper
{
    public readonly Number Value;

    public NumberWrapper(Number value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator NumberWrapper(Number duration)
    {
        return new NumberWrapper(duration);
    }

    public static implicit operator Number(NumberWrapper number)
    {
        return number.Value;
    }
}
```

This code will compile:

```
bool x = new Number(1) < new Number(2);
```

And so of course will this:

```
Number n1 = new NumberWrapper(1);
Number n2 = new NumberWrapper(2);
bool z = n1 < n2;
```

But this won't:

```
bool y = new NumberWrapper(1) < new NumberWrapper(2);
```

because `NumberWrapper` doesn't have an implicit conversion to any type that supports `<` without any further implicit conversions.

Note that all primitive numeric and enumeration types (e.g. char, short, int, long, float, double, decimal, enum) provide built-in comparison operators. All other types can only provide user-defined comparison operators.

User-defined comparison operators look like this:

```
public static bool operator < (MyType lhs, MyType rhs) ...
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain the difference between "user-defined comparison operators" and "built-in comparison operators" just to make it clearer.

Comment: @Magnus: yeah, are operator for TimeSpan are build int? Or built in are operators for primitive types?

Comment: @zgnilec The operators are only built-in for primitive types (as I put at the end of my answer)